# How to make Visual Studio Installer remove file during installation?

Tags: visual-studio-setup-proje

I already had [trouble finding out where appSettings get stored when the app is installed in program files directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72251882/4541566).

Now the next thing is finding out how to make the app installer update that location too. Because obviously, Microsoft Windows doesn't do it.

When the app is installed in program files and you try to update its settings file the setting file actually got saved to another location: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\company\app

How to make Visual Studio Installer remove this file during installation?

Comment: There are multiple mistakes here, possibly one triggering another.  The scope of the setting you modify must be `user`, not `application`, so it is automatically saved in a writable appdata folder.  And the manifest embedded in the app is not correct, it is missing the `requestedExecutionLevel` element, that's how the file ended up in VirtualStore.  Get this right, and bump up the application version, and there's no need to fight the machine.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks, but the app was built that way already before this app was distributed and used in a folder, now I want to create an installer without changing much of its structure, look I found a way - I will install the appSettings file in VirtualStore too that way it will always have current version